# send variable to catch from outside of promise in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I try to make bot for telegram and use [telegram-node-bot](https://github.com/Naltox/telegram-node-bot) for this. I unpload my bot on server, now makes some fixs and reload it. After this in my console I got telegram API errors with message that I cant send messages to users that was banned or blocked my bot. I can catch this errors easy if I try to send a message like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++){
  let uid = users[i].chatid;
  tg.api.sendMessage(uid, "Hello, world!")
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('err = '+JSON.stringify(err))
      console.log('uid = '+uid) // undefined
    })
}
```

In output of this will be result like this:

```
err = {"_code":403,"_description":"Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user"}
```

And... and this dont let me do nothing cuz `uid` still *undefined*, and I cant do nothing with this error. How to pass `uid` to this catch?

Comment: what is the value of `users[i].chatid`

Comment: numbers like 1231423

Comment: so, console.log(uid0 before the sendMessage is OK?

Comment: aye all fine output before sendMessage looks good

Comment: does your code do anything with `uid` after the code shown - (but still in the for loop) ? the loop shown is not complete

Comment: realy... i tryed to use `users[i]` that is an **Object** but not a `uid` that is **number**. now i tryed to pick `uid` and all works...

Comment: @NikitaM it has nothing to do with `Object` vs `Number`. It has to do that in one case you are using the `i` variable without a closure. If you use `let` in the `for` it would work with the `users[i]` as well. `for(let i=0;i<users.length;i++){`

Comment: In your example, if `uid` has the value `undefined` then `users[i].chatid` must be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
const Fail = function(detail)=>{this.detail=detail;};
Promise.all(
  users.map(
    user =>
      tg.api.sendMessage(user.chatid, "Hello, world!")
      .then(
        undefined,//do not handle resolve, do that later
        err => new fail([err,user])
      )
  )  
)
.then(
  results => {
    const sucesses = results.filter(result=>(result&&result.constructor)!==Fail);
    const failures = results.filter(result=>(result&&result.constructor)===Fail);
    console.log("all chats completed ,"+failures.length+" failed");
    console.log(
      "failure details:"
    );
    failures.forEach(
      fail=>{
        cosnt [reason,user] = fail.detail;
        console.log("failed because:",reason,"for user:",user.chatid);    
      }
    )
  }
);
```

Please let me know if you need more help.

The reason your code didn't work:

Since your code actually shows no problems I have to guess that one of the users doesn't have a chatid or that you are using `var uid` or anything really.

A `let` binding is scoped within the for/while/if block but a `var` binding is scoped within a function (or global if outside a function).

Here I'm using `let` binding and see it outputs expected results:

```
var i = -1,numbers=[1,2,3,4,5],promises=[];
while(++i<5){
  let number = numbers[i]; // using let, should work as expected
  console.log("in in the while loop",number);
  promises.push(Promise.resolve("")
    .then(
      _=>console.log("In resolved promise number is now:",number)
    )
  );
}
console.log("after while loop",i);
Promise.all(promises)
.then(x=>console.log("all promises resolved"))
```

This uses `var` binding so you get "unexpected" results

```
var i = -1,numbers=[1,2,3,4,5],promises=[];
while(++i<5){
  var number = numbers[i]; // using var, should have "unexpected" results
  console.log("in in the while loop",number);
  promises.push(Promise.resolve("")
    .then(
      _=>console.log("In resolved promise number is now (should be 5)",number)
    )
  );
}
console.log("after while loop",i);
Promise.all(promises)
.then(x=>console.log("all promises resolved"))
```